# How to translate files, placed in Drupal's 'include' directory?

Tags: drupal

I need to load translation for all files inside "include" directory during Drupal installation

It's no problem to do that for modules, I just need to create 'translations' directory inside each of the modules and place "language_code.po" into this directory.

I've tried the same for "includes" and had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Most drupal core has been translated.  You will need to download the proper language pack in order to use those languages.

Take a look at http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/locale and http://drupal.org/node/21145

Comment: Andrew Sledge,thanks, I saw these links. I asked how to load automatically translations for files in 'include' directory upon installation since they can not be translated in the usual manner (like modules) I can, of course, merge all these translations to one big file and place that somewhere in module directory but for some reasons won't do that